# Errror en ejecución de Python usando funciones

Tags: python, funciones, condiciones, else

Seré breve: No encuentro el error que no me permite compilar. Pero tiene que ver con la línea 26 de mi código, en donde empiezo la estrcutura if:

```
#Calculo de áreas:
Pi = 3.141516

#Area del cuadrado:
def AreaCuadrado():
 L = float(input("¿Cuál es el valor del lado?"))
 X = L ** 2
 print("\n El área del cuadrado es" + X + " unidades cuadradad.")

#Area del triángulo
 def AreaTriangulo():
 B = float(input("¿Cuál es el valor de la base?"))
 A = float(input("¿Cuál es el valor de la altura?"))
 Y = (B * A) / 2
 print ("\n El área del triángulo es: " +Y+" unidades cuadradas.")

 #Area del círculo:
 def AreaCirculo():
 R = float(input("Ingrese el valor del radio: "))
 Z = (R * Pi)/2
 print("\n El área del círculo es: " + Z + "unidades cuadradas.")

 Run = 1
 while Run == 1:
 Seleccion = int(input("\nSeleccione la función a ejecutar: \n1- Áre de un cuadrado \n2-Área de un triangulo \n3- Área de un círculo.")
 if Seleccion == 1:
    AreaCuadrado()
 elif Seleccion == 2:
    AreaTriangulo
 elif Seleccion = 3:
    AreaCirculo()
 else:
    print("Opción incorrecta. Intente de nuevo.")
 Run = int(input("\n ¿Desea seleccionar otra función? \n 1- SI \n 2- NO"))
```

A parte del error de sintaxis en la línea 26 no encuentro ningún otro detalle en donde considere que estoy cometiendo errores.
La idea es correo un pequeño menú que me permita seleccionar cuantas veces quiera cada uno de las funciones previamente creadas.
Estoy ocupando Python 3.7.3

Comment: Hola Gabriel, aparte de problemas con la identación (supongo que causados al copiar el código) te falta cerrar un paréntesis en la línea anterior a la que comentas, sería `Seleccion = int(input("\nSeleccione la función a ejecutar: \n1- Áre de un cuadrado \n2-Área de un triangulo \n3- Área de un círculo."))`. Ese es el error de sintaxis que comentas.

Comment: Aparte de eso la línea  `elif Seleccion = 3:` debe ser  `elif Seleccion == 3:` y te falta llamar a `AreaTriangulo` (te falta el paréntesis, `AreaTriangulo()`). Son todos errores tipográficos, lo único que queda es un error en los `print` de las funciones, no puedes concatenar una cadena con float, debes hacer `print("\n El área del cuadrado es" + str(X) + " unidades cuadradas.")` o, mucho mejor, usa literales de cadena formateados : `print(f"\n El area del cuadrado es {X} unidades cuadradas.")`. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola mira te hacían falta cerrar el paréntesis de 
"Seleccion" y no habías llamado correctamente a la función "AreaTriangulo" ni tampoco comparaste correctamente el ultimo "elif" puesto que sólo tenías un igual y no dos (asignación y comparación respectivamente).

Tampoco debes concatenar utilizando el símbolo "+" ya que esto es un operador de suma. No hagas caso del que te recomendó encerrar la variable entre llaves ( no se de dónde saca eso).

Te dejo el mismo código con los errores corregidos:

```
# Calculo de áreas:
Pi = 3.141516

# Area del cuadrado:


def AreaCuadrado():
    L = float(input("¿Cuál es el valor del lado?"))
    X = L ** 2
    #Para concatenar se utiliza la "," en lugar del simbolo +
    print("\n El área del cuadrado es", X ," unidades cuadradad.")

# Area del triángulo


def AreaTriangulo():
    B = float(input("¿Cuál es el valor de la base?"))
    A = float(input("¿Cuál es el valor de la altura?"))
    Y = (B * A) / 2
    print("\n El área del triángulo es: ", Y," unidades cuadradas.")

# Area del círculo:


def AreaCirculo():
    R = float(input("Ingrese el valor del radio: "))
    print("1")
    Z = (R * Pi) / 2
    print("2")
    print("\n El área del círculo es: ",Z,"unidades cuadradas.")


Run = 1
while Run == 1:
    Seleccion = int(input("\nSeleccione la función a ejecutar: \n1- Áre de un cuadrado \n2-Área de un triangulo \n3- Área de un círculo."))
    if Seleccion == 1:
        AreaCuadrado()
    elif Seleccion == 2:
        AreaTriangulo()
    elif Seleccion == 3:
        AreaCirculo()
    else:
        print("Opción incorrecta. Intente de nuevo.")
        Run = int(input("\n ¿Desea seleccionar otra función? \n 1- SI \n 2- NO"))
```

Buena suerte amigo espero te sirva.

Comment: Dado que soy el que recomendó "Encerrar la variable entre llaves" :),  se llama literales de cadena formateados, disponibles desde Python 3.6... [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). El problema de esa línea no es usar el operador `+` en si (se pueden concatenar cadenas con él sin problemas), falla porque se intenta concatenar dos tipos distintos (`str` y `float`) y Python jamás cambia el tipo de una variable de forma implícita. Un saludo.